# How can I use an arm64 emulator on Android studio on a Windows PC to run Snapchat APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, arm64, windows-arm64

Recently I hired a developer to create some scripts using the Snapchat APK. It works perfectly using an arm64 emulator on Mac with just about any Snapchat APK. The issue is I'm unable to run arm64 emulators on my windows pc and all of the Snapchat APKs seems to not be compatible with any x86 architecture. I'm completely unable to run the program at this point.

When dragging this APK: https://snapchat.en.uptodown.com/android/download onto a x86 emulator I get this error message: Failed to commit install session 1148191625 with command package install-commit 1148191625. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

I instantly get this message when trying to run an arm64 emulator: "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_6_Pro_API_30 has terminated. Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: Why would you use an x86 emulator if you know the target binary is arm64?

Comment: The Android x86 emulator images for Android 11 and 12 for GoogleAPI should include an ARM emulation. May be older and/or newer versions, too.